# Copy only files from one directory to another

Tags: unix, cp

I'd like to copy a content of directory 1 to directory 2.
However, I'd like to only copy files (and not directories) from my directory 1. How can I do that ?

```
cp dir1/* dir2/*
```

then I still have the directories issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use this in dir1

```
find . -type f -exec cp{} dir2/ \;
```

Comment: Just add a space between cp and {} to make this command work as wanted

Answer (score 2):

You may try this one

```
cp dir1/*.* dir2/*
```

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't work, because some file doesn't have any extension.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
find dir1 -type f -exec cp {} dir2/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The currently approved solution will work, however if sub-directories exist, this will also copy the files from the subfolders as well, but instead of putting the copied files in sub folders, it will copy them to dir1.

`/dir1/dir1a/test.txt` will end up as `dir1/test.txt`

`-maxdepth` can be used to only copy files in `dir1`:

```
find dir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} dir2/ \;
```